# Find a group which only has values meeting a set criteria in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

[image]

I need to select Forests which  have IDs with areas more than 30.5Ha only. Desired outcome;
[image]

I have tried;

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Min(AreaHa)OVER(partition BY Forest)
        FROM   REPORT)a
WHERE  AreaHa> 30.5
```

Your help will highly be appreciated

Comment: Why no qw 60.7 ?

Comment: Because interested in forests which are solely constituted by ids with areas greater than 30.5Ha only

Answer (score 3):

Do you try filter by MinArea?

```
SELECT forest, ID, areaha,patchclass
FROM   (SELECT *,
           Min(AreaHa)OVER(partition BY Forest) AS MinArea
    FROM   REPORT)a
WHERE  MinArea> 30.5
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try `having`:

```
select *
from REPORT
where Forest in (
    select Forest
    from REPORT
    group by Forest
    having min(AreaHA) > 30.5
)
```